# Convert a SolrDocumentList to a DocList

Tags: solr, solrj

Is there any way I can convert a SolrDocumentList to a DocList and set it in the QueryResult object?

Or, the workaround adding a SolrDocumentList object to the QueryResult object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a method called [addOrReplaceResults](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/util/SolrPluginUtils.html) in SolrPluginUtils that, given a SolrQueryResponse, replaces the DocList if it is in the result. Otherwise adds it to the response.

Comment: This seems to have been removed, looking at the API for Solr 4 (alpha).